# Помогите пожалуйста с табами

Tags: javascript, php, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
 $(".top_phone .wrapper .tab").click(function() {
 $(".top_phone .wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
 $(".top_phone .tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
 }).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<div class="top_phone">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
          <span class="tab">Контактная барная стойка</span>/
          <span class="tab">Круглосуточная кухня</span>
          <span class="tab">Дымные кальяны </span>/
          <span class="tab">Дружеская атмосфера</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tab_content">
          <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              накормим вас в любое время дня и ночи
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
           <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              кухня
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              кальяны
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              атмосфера
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста с табами, надпись и картинка должна меняться  при переключении и каждые 5 секунд

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос клон https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901876/Помогите-решить-проблему-с-табами

Comment: вообще если прошлому вопросу уделили не достаточно внимания то вы сможете объявить конкурс ... но разумеется что ваш рейтинг очень низкий ... просите кого не будь в личной переписке ..хоть того же @Air он же возможно и поможет

Comment: @Air  если я тот удалю, этот можно оставить ?

Comment: можно удалить любой

Comment: @Air  ок, удалил

Comment: @Air поможете ?

Comment: Извини, не видел твоего последнего  коммента.

Comment: @ Air Здравствуйте, ничего ВАМ еще будет возможность мне помочь :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();

var tabIndex = 0, //индекс текущего таба
    countTabs = $(".tab_item").length - 1, //количество табов
    time = 1000; // время перелистывания, установленно 1сек

$(".top_phone .wrapper .tab").click(function() {
  tabIndex = $(this).index();
  checkTab();
});

setInterval(function(){
  tabIndex++;
  if(tabIndex > countTabs){
    tabIndex = 0;
  }
  checkTab();
}, time);

function checkTab(){
  $(".tab").removeClass("isActive").eq(tabIndex).addClass("isActive");
  $(".top_phone .tab_item")
    .hide()
    .eq(tabIndex)
    .fadeIn();
}
```

```css
.tab.isActive{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top_phone">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
          <span class="tab isActive">Контактная барная стойка</span>/
          <span class="tab">Круглосуточная кухня</span>/
          <span class="tab">Дымные кальяны </span>/
          <span class="tab">Дружеская атмосфера</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tab_content">
          <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              накормим вас в любое время дня и ночи
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
           <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              кухня
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              кальяны
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              атмосфера
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ, спасли мою пятую точку

Comment: Простите за наглость, но ВЫ можете сделать так что одновременно при переходе подсвечивалось и название вкладки ?

Comment: @user312259 Обновил код.

Comment: @ Евгений Николаев спасибо